# Dead Rising 3, side missions, and replaying a chapter

Tags: dead-rising-3

During my earlier chapters I focused on the main story, and completely ignored side missions I picked up.

Now that I feel that I should've played those side missions to get the rewards, if I restart chapter 1, chapter 2, etc. and play through them again, will I get the same side missions as I did the first time? Or have I lost my chance to complete them?

Comment: I haven't played #3, but in the first two, you just had to do things at the right time and follow them through before their timer expired.  (and you might need to do something to trigger their starting)

Answer (score 1):

I guess I can answer my question myself now.

I managed to enter a side-quest boss fight with 1 health by mistake, and could not complete it no matter how many times I tried so I had to restart chapter 3.

One side-quest I didn't make due to timeout was to investigate some lady by a law office. This now popped back into the game, so I guess the answer to my question is yes, the side-quests can be retaken if I restart a chapter.

I don't know if there is a guarantee that all side-quests will appear, or if they're randomly picked, but at least this one quest did reappear for me.

Comment: Im surprises this was never answered. I have just beaten the game; so have provided a better guarantee, in my answer. I think users would have known the answer from previous games, but been unwilling to commit an answer specofically for this one. I would recommend visiting Dead Rising 1 to see just how essential that revert can be.

Answer (score 1):

There is no penalty for revisiting chapters, and all side missions can be revisited.

The Dead Rising series is unique to todays genre of horror in that it the games allow you to revert back to the start of the game, and start fresh, while retaining your character.

This feature is more of an essential, in the first title. A player could too easily find themselves backed into a corner, wether it be a boss fight that is too difficult without further character progression, or a main story mission that requires passing an impossible distance in a small time frame.

At these junctions, you would simply restart, and continue levelling your character, in hopes of achieving the ability needed to move further in the game. By Dead Rising 3, the game is a lot easier, so this mechanic is not stressed as much.

To clarify, you can revert back to any chapter you have completed, or simply restart the game. Your character retains his PP level and skills, a long with any held weapons and known blueprints. Saved survivors, defeated Psychos and cleared safe houses will all reset to the default state at the point in the game you have moved back too. These can all be revisited, wether you intend to correct a failure, or simply earn some more PP.

There are two important things to note:

- Survivors reset. You will need to save them all in a single run to earn the achievement for rescuing all survivors.
- Some side missions require previous actions. For example, there is a certain Psycho mission that appears in the final chapters, but only if you have previoisly rescued a certain survivor.

**Never feel bad about missing side missions in favour of progressing the main story**. The later part of the game provides far greater opportunity to level. **It is undeniably easier to rescue all the survivors once you have a few super combo weapons anf the level 50 skills.**